# How does facebook decide if an Android app is a release or a development version?

Tags: android, facebook

I work on an app that has Facebook integration.

To configure Facebook I can configure release and development key hashes to verify my app during single sign on through the Facebook app.

How decides Facebook if an app is a release or a development app?

Comment: through the signature, probably the same way the playstore knows if your app is signed with the debug certificate

Comment: Facebook doesn't care if you're using a release or development app, it just checks the calling app's signature against all the key hashes you've set in your app settings.

Comment: Yes and there are two different fields for setting up hashes. Development keys and release keys. And if a key is only in the development field the login will not work if facebook thinks the app is a release version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook takes the BuildConfig.DEBUG variable to check this.

I run a test and added the key of a new keystore to the release keys. It works fine if I build the Release build type of the app. If I add the key in the development keys list the keys only work for debug builds.

So there is no different Id or something else that I need to change to tell facebook that I build a development version. If you have no access to the release certificate and want to build a release version for your testing you need to add this key to the release keys as well.